# Is there a way to open a calendar item from an office add-in taskpane?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-web-addins

In the new taskpane office add-ins is there a way to open a meeting in a separate window if you have the meeting invite?

Like I get all the meetings from the call below. Is there a way that I can open one of them if I pass in the meeting id?

```
 var apiurl = `${baseurl}/v1.0/me/calendarview?startdatetime=${dateRange.startdate}&enddatetime=${dateRange.enddate}`;
  
              axios({
                method: "get",
                url: apiurl,
                headers: reqheaders
              })
                .then(response => response.data)
                .then(data => {
                    var dataHold = [];
                    console.log(data.value);
                    for(var i = 0; i < data.value.length; i++){
                      console.log("in for loop");
                      console.log(data.value[i]);
                      let subject = data.value[i].Subject;
                      let starttime = data.value[i].Start;
                      let endtime = data.value[i].End;

                      //get the body
                      //get all the links
                      //check links for teams links
                      //check links for webex links
                      //check the link for zoom meetings
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you are trying to achieve. Are you creating an addin? Have you tried the `webLink` property returned in the response?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I am creating an add-in. When I use the weblink it opens the calendar item in the browser on the web outlook client. I am looking to see if I can have it open the meeting information in the desktop client. Like one the meeting window.

Answer (score 1):

The displayAppointmentForm method opens an existing calendar appointment from an itemId in a new window on the desktop. There is documentation for Office.context.mailbox.displayAppointmentForm and examples [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.mailbox?view=outlook-js-1.5&preserve-view=true#displayAppointmentForm_itemId_).

Please note that if this API is used from an add-in in Outlook desktop, it will open an appointment in desktop. Similarly, if the add-in is used in OWA, it will open the specified form only if the body of the form is less than or equal to 32K characters.